# javascript library for css3 in old browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

Can you link me some javascript libraries, that can give me full support html5 and css3 on all browsers? 
That library must get that support without any css file changing.(e.g. i made some gradients and shadows on page, and i dont want to rewrite them to be fully supported by that library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). You do need to make some minimal changes, but it's definitely the best way to go.

For border-radius and box-shadow you just need to add a line adding a behaviour, for gradients it's a little more.

You might find that you need to add position:relative; to elements to get the grad or shadow to show up.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need *everything*. This list will help you pick the features you realy do need: http://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

**Update:** Gradients and shadows in older Internet Explorers are easily handled by [CSS3 PIE library](http://css3pie.com/).